# why im getting this strip lines

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How to get rid of this strip lines.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tE4O6RKdHxH9grg24qNScuL6EaDgZf8V)

[image]
Below are my nodes. How can i adjust and disappear those lines.

[image]

**uv mapping**

[image]

I tried to adjust the coloramp but did not work. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: can you show us the UV mapping of this mesh?

Comment: @sanbaldo sure here is the link for uv mapping https://imgur.com/gallery/9cURpEk

Comment: Possibly we need to see what's hidden in your 'mountain river' group? Is the displacement aliasing/out of whack with the color? Also, your (adaptive) subdivision settings?

Comment: try to use the UV node as source in the "texture coordinate" node.

Comment: @sanbaldo i tried did not work same result

Comment: so, you should share the blender file.. so we can check it

Comment: @sanbaldo plz check the link file attached. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noise textures need coordinates - object works well for this. Without the texture coordinate nodes, procedural texture nodes will default to generated and this is not always the best one (I almost always choose Object or UV). The relevant nodes are in your Mountain River and Snow White > BMD_SnowBump groups. If you need to debug in the future, try muting your mix nodes one by one and see where the issue comes in. With this, if you mute the last mix node and the displacement node, the banding disappears so you know to look in those bits! (I like to use frames instead of groups so I can see everything and use the node wrangler viewer to see what looks like what)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there is a "noise" node that is generating the problem. try to switch to 2d.

[image]
check this to more details:

[image]

Comment: I think no that issue. I remove the snow node completely and added a default principle bsdf still i can see the lines. https://imgur.com/gallery/yqL4F89

Comment: remove it from the snow bump.. I don't see the green background in your screenshot, are you removing the right one?

Comment: I think u have remove the texture node and have the snow node only. In your image there is only snow and no texture (mountain texture). This is my node with texture still have the lines. https://imgur.com/gallery/jsgzQMH

Comment: try to switch all noise node from 3d to 2d.. it works for me

Comment: i found the solution. And drop the answer. Thanks